# astronvim dap debun in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, neovim

I would like that in astronvim in the dap plugin, I can configure it for debug in angular, I have the user folder and in the init.lua I have this config

```
dap = {
      adapters = {
        chrome = {
          type = "executable",
          command = "node",
          args = {os.getenv("HOME") .. "/path/to/vscode-chrome-debug/out/src/chromeDebug.js"} -- TODO adjust
        }
      },
      configurations = {
        javascriptreact = {
          type = "chrome",
          request = "attach",
          program = "${file}",
          cwd = vim.fn.getcwd(),
          sourceMaps = true,
          protocol = "inspector",
          port = 9222,
          webRoot = "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        typescriptreact = {
          type = "chrome",
          request = "attach",
          program = "${file}",
          cwd = vim.fn.getcwd(),
          sourceMaps = true,
          protocol = "inspector",
          port = 9222,
          webRoot = "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
      }


    }
```

and I use this command to open the debug

```
   google-chrome-stable --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

but nothing I tried worked for me